Visual Studio 2015 RDLC - "Report Parameter" is missing from Report menu

Above is image from Internet.
I am using Visual Studio 2015.
My report menu for RDLC do not have "Report Parameters"
Why is that?
I use "Document Outline' to select the parent in it which is the report itself, then I take a look at report menu, still no report parameters there.
I created a new web application project and added a new RDLC, still no report parameters.
Below is what I see in my menu:

below is my Visual Studio version:

